# Evaluate a derivative of a Expected Value for a Positive Part of a Function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability-theory, expected-value

Let $Z \in L_1$ be a random variable with density $H_Z$. I would like to know how to calculate
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{E}[Z-t]_+.
$$
where $[x]_+:=\max\{x,0\}.$

My attempt: Write
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \mathbb{E}[Z-t]_+ = \frac{d}{dt} \int_t^\infty (z-t) dH_Z(z)
$$
Then I tried the Leibniz integral but I am not sure how to deal with the infinity on the upper limit. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can write $\lim\limits_{b\to \infty}  \frac{d}{dt} \int_t^b (z-t) \ dH_Z(z)$. Now use Leibniz.

Comment: I get $H_Z(t)-1$.

Comment: Thanks, @callculus42 . I am wondering how would you justify the interchange between the limit and derivative?

Comment: I just see no reason against it.